# Pandas Dataframe to tensor

Tags: python, pandas, pytorch

I have a dataframe with 3 columns (a date index, a price and a string symbol).
It looks like that:

| Date | Price | Symbol |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-01-02 | 39.480000 | AAPL |
| 2019-01-02 | 101.120003 | MSFT |
| 2019-01-02 | 62.023998 | TSLA |
| 2019-01-03 | 35.547501 | AAPL |
| 2019-01-03 | 97.400002 | MSFT |
| 2019-01-03 | 60.071999 | TSLA |

I'm looking for some panda/pytorch/python syntactic sugar to turn that into a tensor/matrix that will be:

```
[ [ 39.480000, 101.120003, 62.023998], [35.547501, 97.400002, 60.071999]]
```

With the number length of the first dimension will be the number of unique dates, and the length of the second will be the number of unique symbols.
I'm guaranteed to have exactly 3 symbols per date and I want that each row of my matrix follow the same order for its columns (e.g always AAPL, MSFT, TSLA).

Now, that is very easy with some for loops, but I'm looking for something more "pythonic"

Answer (score 2):

You can `groupby` the date column, convert the groups of `Price` to numpy arrays, and then convert this series to a tensor:

```py
import torch
import pandas as pd

prices = df.groupby(['Date'])['Price'].apply(np.array)
my_tensor = torch.tensor(prices)
```